# Unique Combination of ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a unique Availability status for Player on given Hour. Here goes the code:

```
class Player(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Hour(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTimeField()
  players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True,
                                   through='Availability')

class Availability(models.Model):
  player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  hour = models.ForeignKey(Hour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  available = models.BooleanField()
```

My problem is that it's currently possible to add same Availability few times - I want to programatically limit it to just one per combination.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See docs for [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together). This is enforced in the admin and at the database level. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53425500) below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have the unique_together on the "through" table (in your case the Avaliability Table)

```
class Availability(models.Model):
  player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  hour = models.ForeignKey(Hour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  available = models.BooleanField()  
  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('player','hour'),)
```

And then use the get_or_create for adding/modifying:

```
 obj,created = Availability.objects.get_or_create(hour=hour,player=player)
```

Comment: Minor thing, I think there's a typo, `through`, not `throuh`

Comment: `unique_together` has [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in favor of `UniqueConstraint`.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around it modifying `save()` for `Availability`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        combination = Availability.objects.filter(player=self.player,
                                                  hour=self.hour).first()
        if combination:
            self.pk = combination.pk
    super(Availability, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```